# removing a string of four characters from the front and thirteen characters from the end of a filename

Tags: python, substring

I have seen the basic Python code for a filename replacement in a directory but they are always for known strings, but how would you remove random characters of a certain length?

Would this work?

```
newFileName = file.replace([-5:], "")
```

As I am trying to remove the last five characters from the filename without removing the extension.

Here is an update:
I am trying to do this:

```
DMC-CIWS15-AAAA-A00-00-0000-00A-018A-D_014-00_EN-US.xml
```

to

```
CIWS15-AAAA-A00-00-0000-00A-018A-D.xml
```

which removes DMC- and _014-00_EN-US from the end.

I need to add this to a code that will fix a directory of files.

Comment: Just slice the string: newFileName = file[0:-5]

Comment: @MaximilianPeters, would that not slice off the extension?

Comment: If you need to keep the extension, use rfind: newFileName = file[0:file.rfind('.')]

Comment: You should clarify better what "random" characters exactly you want to remove. What's the criterion/rule?

Comment: This looks like a linguistic problem. He probably means "arbitrary" or "any" character instead of "random" character. That is, for instance, what the `.` symbol in regular expressions is for.

Comment: can you clarify how many characters exactly you want to remove and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem (if I understand it correctly) has a clear separation. Remove extension, remove X characters from beginning and end, and then add the extension again to get the final answer.

```
import os

oldFileName = 'xxxx-filename-xxxxx.XML'
# remove n chars in beginning, m chars at end
n = 5
m = 6
name, ext = os.path.splitext(oldFileName)
# splice away the chars, and add the extension
newFileName = '{}{}'.format(name[0:-m][n:], ext)
# newFileName == 'filename.XML'
```

So in your case, you would use `n=4` and `m=13`.

If you didn't know the length, but you knew you wanted everything up to and including the first dash out, and likewise everything after the first underscore (which would mean there couldn't be underscores in the normal filename or the first part of it), this would work also:

```
import os

oldFileName = 'DMC-CIWS15-AAAA-A00-00-0000-00A-018A-D_014-00_EN-US.xml'
name, ext = os.path.splitext(oldFileName)
newFileName = '{}{}'.format(name[name.index('-')+1:name.index('_')], ext)
# newFileName == 'CIWS15-AAAA-A00-00-0000-00A-018A-D.xml'
```

And even if the pattern is something else, but there is a pattern, you can code to match it, like I have here.

Comment: I have updated the question to be more specific so that you could make any needed changes to your answer if need be. Thanks for your help

Comment: I've updated my answer slightly, but I believe my solution to have been general enough to work for your case, if the length is fixed. However, a nicer solution it seems would be to filter the first dash out, and everything after the first underline, if this is representive of the format.

Answer (score 0):

Its not nice but I hope this works for you tho

If you know the files that you want to rename all have the same length, you can try:

```
>>>file = 'DMC-CIWS15-AAAA-A00-00-0000-00A-018A-D_014-00_EN-US.xml'
>>>ext = file[51:]
>>>newFile = file[4:38]+ext
```

when you print the newFile you now have:

```
>>>print(newFile)
CIWS15-AAAA-A00-00-0000-00A-018A-D.xml
```